# How to replace escaped unicode characters with proper unicode characters?

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I have a string as such:

```
'https://www.jobtestprep.co.uk/media/24543/xnumber-series-big-1.png,qanchor\\u003dcenter,amode\\u003dcrop,awidth\\u003d473,aheight\\u003d352,arnd\\u003d131255524960000000.pagespeed.ic.YolXsWmhs0.png'
```

I need to replace an arbitrary escaped unicode character (`'\\uXXXX'`) with its equivalent *unescaped* unicode character (`'\uXXXX'`). I've got Regex to extract all of the necessary parts (the `'\\uXXXX'` part and the `'XXXX'` part for `re.sub()`) but I can't find a way to replace the right part with `\u{}` as Python gives a Unicode error and wants a pre-filled in character such as `'\u003d'`. Using raw strings doesn't work as `'\u{}'` is just converted back into `'\\u{}'` and we end up back where we started.

Is there a way to do this? If you want an example of the code you can have a look at it here:

```
# data loaded from a https://www.google.com/search image search

results_source = urllib.request.urlopen(url_request).read().decode()
searched_results = re.findall(r"(?<=,\"ou\":\")[^\s]+[\w](?=\",\"ow\")", results_source)

for count, unicode in enumerate(re.findall(r"(?<=\\u)....", searched_results[i])):
    searched_results[i] = re.sub(re.findall(r"\\u....", searched_results[i])[count], r"\u{}".format(unicode), searched_results[i])
```

`searched_results` is a list of results returned. An example of an item in the list would be the string given above.

Comment: Please reduce your code to a *minimal example*. We don't need this much code.

Comment: Sorry, I was just trying to provide context for the issue. The actual question could be answered without any code as an example. I'll cut the code down, anyway :)

Comment: You appear to be extracting Javascript / JSON strings from a Google result page, so just treat the data as JSON data. Use `json.loads()`. But keep the `"` quotes around the strings in that case.

Comment: Also, consider using a HTML parsing library like BeautifulSoup, and `requests` to handle your HTTP request needs.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: that's actually the wrong advice for this context, it'll produce wrong results for non-BMP codepoints because the syntax here is Javascript / JSON specific, not Python specific.

Comment: Switch to using `r"(?<=,\"ou\":)\"[^\s]+[\w]\"(,\"ow\")", results_source)` and map each result through `json.loads()`. Or load the *whole* data structure from the page and pass it to `json.loads()` once, then traverse the resulting Python datastructure.

Comment: When using BeautifulSoup, I can get the same URLs with `[json.loads(t.text)['ou'] for t in soup.select('.rg_meta')]`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll give it a go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex extracts *JSON strings* from a webpage:

```
searched_results = re.findall(r"(?<=,\"ou\":\")[^\s]+[\w](?=\",\"ow\")", results_source)
```

Those `"` chacarters you removed were actually significant. The `\uxxxx` escape syntax here is specific to JSON (and Javascript) syntax; they are closely related to Python's use but different (not much, but it matters when you have non-BMP codepoints).

You can trivially decode them as JSON , if you keep the quotes in there:

```
searched_results = map(json.loads, re.findall(r"(?<=,\"ou\":)\"[^\s]+[\w]\"(?=,\"ow\")", results_source))
```

Better still would be to use a HTML library to parse the page. When using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), you can get the data with:

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(results_source, 'html.parser')
search_results = [json.loads(t.text)['ou'] for t in soup.select('.rg_meta')]
```

This loads the text contents of each `<div class="rg_meta" ...>` element as JSON data, and extracts the `ou` key from each of the resulting dictionaries. No regular expressions required.

Comment: I was going to use BeautifulSoup (used it in the past) but I figured as I was doing only minimal parsing, I'd just stick to good ol' Regex. In hindsight, it's better just to suck it up and use the Soup so I'll edit my code a bit. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do in this way.

```
>>> url = (
...    'https://www.jobtestprep.co.uk/media/24543/xnumber-series-'
...    'big-1.png,qanchor\\u003dcenter,amode\\u003dcrop,awidth\\u003d473,'
...    'aheight\\u003d352,arnd\\u003d131255524960000000.pagespeed.ic.YolXsWmhs0.png'
... )
>>> url = url.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
>>> print(url)
https://www.jobtestprep.co.uk/media/24543/xnumber-series-big-1.png,qanchor=center,amode
=crop,awidth=473,aheight=352,arnd=131255524960000000.pagespeed.ic.YolXsWmhs0.png
>>>
```